# "TypeError" message while performing quad integration method of scipy.integrate with mpmath functions

Tags: scipy, numerical-integration, integral, mpmath, quad

I am trying to calculate two integrals using `scipy.integrate.quad.` However, since *gamma* functions with *negative* first parameter are not defined in `scipy`, I had to choose the version from `mpmath`. After running the following code,

```
from scipy.integrate import *
from mpmath import *



low, up  = 5.630e5, 1.167e12
alpha, threshold = 1.05   , 2.15e10 
beta = 274

def g(x, beta, low, up):
    return gamma(-2/3) * (gammainc(-2/3, beta*(x/low)**3) - gammainc(-2/3, beta*(x/up)**3))

def Integrand1(x, low, threshold, alpha):
    return pow(x/threshold, alpha) * g

def Integrand2(x, up, threshold):
    return g

Integral1 = quad(Integrand1, low, threshold, args=(low, up, threshold, alpha, beta))
Integral2 = quad(Integrand2, threshold, up, args=(low, up, threshold, beta))

print(Integral1)
print(Integral2)
```

Here is the error message which I don't know how to handle and need help with it:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 19, in
>   
>       Integral1 = quad(Integrand1, low, threshold, args=(low, up, threshold, alpha, beta))   File
>   "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpmath/calculus/quadrature.py",
>   line 748, in quad
>       points[0], prec, epsilon, m, verbose)   File "/home/username/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpmath/calculus/quadrature.py",
>   line 215, in summation
>       for i in xrange(len(points)-1): TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

I can only guess that the reason could be `quad` function is not compatible with integrals defined using `mpmath.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Import statements

Don't import * from two places, it's a recipe for name collision. MpMath has its own [`quad`](http://mpmath.org/doc/1.0.0/calculus/integration.html#mpmath.quad) method, which replaces SciPy's `quad` in your code.

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from mpmath import gamma, gammainc
```

#### Function parameters

If you are calling function `g`, you have to provide arguments to it. So, write `* g(x, beta, low, up)` instead of `* g`.

Of course, these arguments must also be available to the function that is calling `g`. Like this:

```
def Integrand1(x, low, up, threshold, alpha, beta):
    return pow(x/threshold, alpha) * g(x, beta, low, up)

def Integrand2(x, low, up, threshold, alpha, beta):
    return g(x, beta, low, up)

Integral1 = quad(Integrand1, low, threshold, args=(low, up, threshold, alpha, beta))
Integral2 = quad(Integrand2, threshold, up, args=(low, up, threshold, alpha, beta))
```

Note that the arguments passed to Integrand functions match what they expect to receive. They get x, and everything listed in `args` parameter of quad.

No errors are thrown by the code above. I am not sure the operation is meaningful mathematically, as you use `threshold` both for scaling and as an upper limit, but that's another story.

Comment: @thanks, initially I had g function written down explicitly as its function of parameters. But yes, I had too main issues. The statement and the inclusion of parameters in all stages.